# How do I fit a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier with multiple features in sci-kit?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am trying to fit a MultinomialNB classifier in sci-kit with multiple features, but I am getting a Value Error whenever I try. This is my dataframe:

```
data = {"embedding":[[0, 3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 6, 8, 11]],
       "mention": [0, 1, 1],
       "y_label": [0, 0, 1]}

df_training = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

When I try to fit using only one feature, it works fine. For instance, the following yields no problem:

```
X = df_training["embedding"].to_list()
y = df_training["y_label"]

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

However, when I try to add another feature, the following causes a value error:

```
X = df_training[["embedding", "mention"]]
y = df_training["y_label"]

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried casting X as a numpy array, but the problem persists. Any ideas on why this is happening? I feel like fitting with multiple features should be fairly straightforward, and that maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit the classifier to a dataset of multiple features, however I believe the format is incorrect! If you print X, you will see it looks like this:

```
           embedding  mention
0   [0, 3, 5, 7]        0
1   [1, 4, 6, 8]        1
2  [2, 6, 8, 11]        1
```

However it should look like:

```
   emb1  emb2  emb3  emb4  mention
0     0     3     5     7        0
1     1     4     6     8        1
2     2     6     8    11        1
```

The embedding column should be broken up, as each element of the embedding is in itself an individual feature! Try this code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import pandas as pd

data = {"embedding":[[0, 3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 6, 8, 11]],
       "mention": [0, 1, 1],
       "y_label": [0, 0, 1]}

df_training = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

X = df_training["embedding"].to_list()
y = df_training["y_label"]

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)

df_training[['emb1','emb2','emb3','emb4']] = pd.DataFrame(df_training.embedding.tolist(), index= df_training.index)

X = df_training[['emb1','emb2','emb3','emb4', "mention"]]
y = df_training["y_label"]

print(X)
print(y)
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was just an example, but in my actual notebook, my embeddings are each of size 256, and I only have 24 rows of training data. Isn't it inadvisable to have "fat" data frames, that have more columns than rows?

Comment: Yes, you should try to get more data! Probably your classifier wont fit the data well with only 24 examples!